# Query that finds objects with ANY TWO association ids (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**BACKGROUND:** Posts have many Communities through CommunityPosts. I understand the following query returns posts associated with ANY ONE of these community_ids.

```
Post.joins(:communities).where(communities: { id: [1,2,3] })
```

**OBJECTIVE:** I'd like to query for posts associated with ANY TWO community_ids in the array. Having either communities 1 and 2, communities 1 and 3, or communities 2 and 3.

EDIT: Please assume that length of the array is unknown. Used this array of explanation purposes. It will be current_user.community_ids instead of [1,2,3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you all posts having *exactly* any two associations from the current user's communities:

```
Post.select("posts.*, count(distinct(communities.id))").joins(:communities).where("communities.id in (?)", current_user.community_ids).group("posts.id").having("count(distinct(communities.id)) = 2")
```

Apparently, to relax the restriction, you'll need to change the condition in the having clause to >=.